# What does this joke mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

> You wanna know what line doesn't work on a harp player?
>
> “Hey baby, wanna pluck?”

It's a joke from a sitcom. I think I understood its general meaning but I don't understand what a "line on a harp player" is. And pluck?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Harpists pluck strings. What does pluck rhyme with? Would you consider it a good *pick-up line*? Even with the 'punny' substitution?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's a rubbishy "joke", not particularly relevant to English usage as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "rubbishy" is relative, one man's trash is another man's treasure. but more importantly, the use of line here is not obvious. two dictionary definitions, with 12+ each per, did not mention anything about a line being used to pick up a hopeful mate.

Comment: @albert: What can I say? It's a rubbish[y] *question*, too. And medica had already explained both ***line = pick-up line*** and the "rhyming pun" even before Janus answered. And ***he*** got two upvotes for answering a question that no-one else could be bothered to upvote (which is pretty bad - any old rubbish usually gets at least one or two if it's not quickly closed). In fact, now you've called my attention to this. I'll add another upvote (for *isn’t particularly funny*). I'm tempted to closevote the question (it's *really* rubbish! :), but I'll reserve judgement for the time being.

Comment: Almost three years and no mention of pheasants....

Answer (score 4):

A ‘line’ is a pick-up line here: something someone (usually a guy) says to someone (usually a girl) in order to get in their pants.

‘Pluck’ can sometimes be used as a euphemism for ‘fuck’; but it is also the verb used for playing the harp: you pluck the strings of the harp when you play it.

I’m not sure why that would mean that this line *doesn’t* work on harp players (it would be just as logical to me that harp players would be exactly where it *would* work)—but that’s not part of the joke. Which isn’t particularly funny, incidentally.

Comment: Pluck as a euphemism? I've never heard that before.

Comment: It’s not very common (though in this context here, it’s obvious). [Fanciful, but one source here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=PLUCK%20YOU); and a [slightly more serious one here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=214887).

Comment: It doesn't have to be a euphemism.  It just plain rhymes and can be misheard.